# Variable importance for Random Forest classification in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart, random-forest

I performed RF classification in GEE and calculated variable importance with two various scripts successfully.
The first script is:

```
var dict = classifier01.explain();
print('Explain 1:',dict);

var variable_importance = ee.Feature(null, ee.Dictionary(dict).get('importance'));

var chart1 =
ui.Chart.feature.byProperty(variable_importance)
.setChartType('ColumnChart')
.setOptions({ 
title: 'RF Variable Importance - Method 1',
legend: {position: 'none'},
hAxis: {title: 'Bands'},
vAxis: {minValue:0, title: 'Importance'},
});

print(chart1, 'Relative Importance');
```

The chart obtained from this script is:

[image]

The second script and its result are:

```
print(classifier01.explain(), 'Explain 2:')

var importance = ee.Dictionary(classifier01.explain().get('importance'))

var sum = importance.values().reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())

var relativeImportance = importance.map(function(key, val) {
   return (ee.Number(val).multiply(100)).divide(sum)
  })
print(relativeImportance, 'Relative Importance')

var importanceFc = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(null, relativeImportance)
])

var chart2 = ui.Chart.feature.byProperty({
  features: importanceFc
}).setOptions({
      title: 'RF Variable Importance - Method 2',
      vAxis: {title: 'Importance'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Bands'}
  })
print(chart2, 'Relative Importance')
```

[image]

The OOB error is the same in both methods. Now I am confused about which script and graph is correct or better representative of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

These are essentially same. Second one is relative values (ie. share in total). What you having is mostly scale effect. Maybe you can try to narrow scale of axis at first chart.